# Downloading archives from sourceforge.net in a script

Tags: scripting, automation, sourceforge

I am writing a script which installs something (for a user, not as the root; so
no use of the package manager) involving an archive which is part of a
SourceForge project. Now, SourceForge have HTML pages which auto-select a mirror
for you and trigger the download with a delay; this won't work when you're
trying to just:

```
wget --continue alfa.com/bravo.tar.gz
```

What should I / can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work fine:

```sh
q=downloads.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/2.2.0/expat-2.2.0.tar.bz2
timeout 1 wget "$q"
wget --continue "$q"
```

Result:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 414352 (405K), 168838 (165K) remaining [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘expat-2.2.0.tar.bz2’

expat-2.2.0.tar.bz2 100%[+++++++++++========>] 404.64K   235KB/s    in 0.7s

2017-01-21 19:15:57 (235 KB/s) - ‘expat-2.2.0.tar.bz2’ saved [414352/414352]
```

Comment: Whaddaya know, that works... I guess the website behaves different for different User Agent strings.